# Last executed statement in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, debugging, stored-procedures

Is there a way to print the last executed SQL statement wihin a stored procedure?

I found out about

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@@SPID)
```

but that only prints the last bigger portion, i.e. the procedure run. I'd like to accomplish the same for each statement run from within the stored procedure.

We have a huge procedure with about 30 SQL statements. We'd like this procedure to output all the SQL statements when run with @debug = 1 parameter. We've had success with doing that when the queries are dynamic and constructed into a varchar that is run with EXEC, but what about non-dynamic queries? Is it possible to print those as well?

Comment: May be just duplicate the code and do a print of string?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Thanks for the suggestion. The risk of someone changing the query but not the printout is a bit too high for my taste. Also it adds a lot of maintenance due to all changes having to be made twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this may be of help, dug this one out of an old library of scripts. Should show the last queries run in order of newest first. You can add `TOP n` to the select if you just want a few of them.

```
SELECT ProcName = COALESCE(OBJECT_NAME(S2.objectid), 'Ad-Hoc'),
       s1.execution_count,
       sql_statement = (SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(S2.TEXT, S1.statement_start_offset / 2 + 1, ((CASE
                                                                                               WHEN S1.statement_end_offset = -1 THEN (LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), S2.TEXT)) * 2)
                                                                                               ELSE S1.statement_end_offset
                                                                                             END) - S1.statement_start_offset) / 2 + 1)),
       S1.last_execution_time
FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS S1
       CROSS APPLY sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(s1.sql_handle) AS S2
ORDER  BY last_execution_time DESC
```

Comment: Interesting! I'll have to play around with this.